# Error HRESULT: 0x80070021 when connecting to scanner

Tags: c#, wia

I have the following code for scanning a document using WIA with a Kodak ScanMate i1120

```
public static Device InitScanner(string DeviceID)
    {

        var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();

        // Create an empty variable to store the scanner instance
        DeviceInfo firstScannerAvailable = null;

        // Loop through the list of devices
        for (int i = 1; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++)
        {

            if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].DeviceID == DeviceID)
            {
                firstScannerAvailable = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i];
                var device = firstScannerAvailable.Connect();
                return _ConnectedScanner;
            }

        }

        return _ConnectedScanner;
      }

public void ScanDocument()
    {
        string _DeviceID = GetDeviceID(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDevice);

        InitScanner(_DeviceID);


        if (_ConnectedScanner == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Scanner is not turned on or connected");
            Lcontinue = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {

                _item = _ConnectedScanner.Items[1] as Item;
                SelectDeviceDocumentHandling(_ConnectedScanner, DeviceDocumentHandling.Feeder);
                //MessageBox.Show(GetDeviceProperty(_ConnectedScanner, 3078).ToString());
                _MyImage = (ImageFile)_ConnectedScanner.Items[1].Transfer();
                DocCount++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                switch (ex.HResult)
                {

                    case -2145320959:

                        Lcontinue = false;
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "Unknown Error");
                        return;

                    case -2145320957:

                        if (DocCount == 0)
                        {
                            Lcontinue = false;
                            //_WaitForOperator = false;
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "There is no paper in the ADF");
                            return;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Lcontinue = false;
                            //WaitForOperator = false;
                            //DocCount = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case -2145320954:

                        if (DocCount == 0)
                        {
                            Lcontinue = false;
                            //_WaitForOperator = false;
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "The device is busy, Please retry");
                            return;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Lcontinue = false;
                            DocCount = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:

                        Lcontinue = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Error No : " + ex.HResult + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
                        return;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

I have two scanners on the system, a Kyocera and the Kodak, but I only want to use the Kodak for this app.

When I try to scan with the Kodak I get error

HRESULT: 0x80070021
System.IO.FileLoadException: `The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

the error happens on the following line

```
var device = firstScannerAvailable.Connect();
```

I have no other scanning applications open so I am unable to figure out what is locking the file.

Can someone see what would be causing the file lock?

Comment: It is a USB device.  It looks like the WIA (scanner api) already has the device connected.  I don't think you need following since it is already connected : firstScannerAvailable.Connect();

Comment: if I don't use this then _Connected scanner is null and the scan document code doesn't run

Comment: Then your code must be connecting to the device more than once.  Test and only connect if you are not already connected.